# Regular action of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $G\setminus\{1\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4830105/1092170), if $G$ is a finite group and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts *transitively* on $G\setminus\{1\}$, then $G$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, for some prime $p$.

**Q**. If $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts *regularly* (=transitively+freely) on $G\setminus\{1\}$, then does this furtherly constraint the structure of $G$?

**Motivation**. I know that $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)$ acts regularly on $C_p\setminus\{1\}$, but I guess that the other direction is not true. Or perhaps it is true, and a way to the proof is showing that the existence of a subgroup $(G\ge)H\cong C_q\times C_q$ ($q$ prime) would prevent the existence of such a regular action?

Comment: If $G = C_p^n$ then $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \cong \mathrm{GL}_n(p)$. If the stabilizer of a point is trivial then $n=1$.

Comment: By the way, the following similar question is a classic (and important). What can you say about $G$ if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is $2$-transitive on $G \setminus \{1\}$? ...$3$-transitive? (If you get stuck, see Wielandt, *Finite permutation groups*, Theorem 11.1.)

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer which doesn't assume upfront the knowledge of the isomorphism class of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, but gets the sought result just from the assumption that  $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts regularly on the nontrivial elements of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ on $G-\{1\}$ is transitive, we know that every nontrivial element has the same order. In particular, $G$ must be a group of exponent $p$ for some prime $p$.

Since $G$ is a $p$-group, it has nontrivial center. If $g\in Z(G)-\{1\}$, then every image of $g$ under an automorphism is nontrivial and central, so transitivity of the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ gives us that every nontrivial element is central, so $G$ is an abelian $p$-group of exponent $p$. Hence $G$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group.

Thus, $G\cong C_p^n$ for some $n\geq 0$.

If $n\geq 2$, then the automorphism that swaps the first and second coordinate and leaves the rest fixed has a nontrivial fixed point (the element $(x,x,1,\ldots,1)$), so the action is not free.

Thus, if the action is transitive and free, then $n\leq 1$.

Conversely, for $n=0$, the action on $G-\{1\}$ is vacuously regular. For $n=1$, either $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is trivial (when $p=2$), or else an automorphism sends the generator $x$ to $x^a$ for some $a$, $1\leq a\lt p$. If $x^r = x^{ar}$, then $r\equiv ar\pmod{p}$, hence $1\equiv a\pmod{p}$, so the automorphism is the identity element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, showing the action is free. The action is transitive on $G-\{1\}$ since $x\mapsto x^a$ yields an automorphism for each $a$, $1\leq a\lt p$.